# CSS text wrapping issue on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, cross-browser

What can cause the following to happen: If anyone has dealt with this in the past I'm sure you know what is causing it. Keep in mind i have a width of 960px and min-width of 960px. all text is in %.

[image]

Comment: Could you show this HTML page and its CSS (maybe on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/))?

Comment: No way too much work.. Was hoping someone had a similar problem and knew a solution and could quickly make a suggestion.. I was able to use `white-space:nowrap` to get the desired look. For now it will suffice.

Comment: Without the source, there's no information to go on.  You don't say how wide anything is, other than something being at 960px (you do know that mobile devices are a lot less than that, right?) and something being a % (A paragraph?  How wide?).

Comment: Yeah the layout is set 960px, font is set in % - it's very strange behavior. The code has nothing arbitrary that would cause such result. It's just font-size:300% and color, etc. Positioning is absolute.. its just awkward behavior and I was curious if anyone else ever experienced something similar.